# How to key out a white background in compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, masking, chromakey

I've been trying for hours to remove my white (well, grayish white) background from a video, and I thought you could remove it with keying nodes in the compositor (cycles).  I managed to get somewhat close, but it still has pieces of white, and it affects the colour of my sunglasses.  I've tried tutorials meant for green screens, keying/chroma/difference/luminosity nodes, but I just can't figure out the right settings.  Core matte mask helped a little, but made it impossible because my body moves in the video.  I played around with the keying colour a lot, and nothing seems to help.

Is this possible or is a green screen absolutely necessary?

I've attached the .blend file with a screenshot rather than the whole video due to file size, but I imagine it's the same principle.

Here's a screenshot of the original image:

[image]

Here's the node setup:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see, with this setup you get pretty far.

Of course you should mask out roughly your body before, so that it won't "hurt" your face ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Seems so simple and effective.  Only thing is, I move in this video...if I mask the body, how could I make it so that it doesn't cut out when I move?

Comment: If you move you have to use the tracking feature of the video sequencer - but this is a second question...

Comment: Ah thank you! I'm learning about that now.